# mysql fulltext search not returning most relevant results first

Tags: mysql, search, full-text-search

Right now I'm using the following mysql query

```
SELECT * FROM songs WHERE MATCH (title,artist) AGAINST ('$ser' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Now it's working but not very well.

For example say I have the following terms in my database

```
Term One
Term Two
Term Three
```

and I do a search for Term Three

```
$ser = 'Term Three'
```

it's simply returning

```
Term One
Term Two
Term Three
```

So it's matching Term but it's not giving Term Three a higher priority having both Term and Three and I'm not sure what to do to get it to appear above the others.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With MyISAM tables, "three" is a [stopword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-stopwords.html) by default, therefore it is not indexed, and it is ignored in all searches.

If you are indeed using MyISAM tables, then you could specify your own custom list of stopwords, or disable the feature altogether, via the [`ft_stopword_file`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_stopword_file) server option (MyISAM).

NB: For InnoDB tables, [`innodb_ft_server_stopword_table`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_ft_server_stopword_table) is the option to look for. "three" seems no to be a stopword by default for InnoDB, but the list of stopwords may be different on your server.

---

[edit]

I totally overlooked that boolean searches [do not sort results automatically](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-boolean.html) by relevance (as natural language searches do). All you need to do is add an ORDER BY clause (please [test it here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf873/7)):

```
SELECT * FROM songs WHERE MATCH (title,artist) AGAINST ('$ser' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY MATCH (title,artist) AGAINST ('$ser' IN BOOLEAN MODE) DESC
```

Comment: this was just an example, the actual terms contain no stop words and are yielding the same results.

Comment: @BelginFish On second thought, I think all you need to do is add an `ORDER BY` clause. Please review my edit.